# getting error in my code like PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUM_LARGE"

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE

  num_small number :=20

 num_large number :=10

 temp NUMBER;

BEGIN 

IF num_small > num_large THEN

 temp := num_small;

 num_small := num_large;

 num_large := temp;
  
 END IF;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('num_small BEFORE = 20, AFTERWARDS = ' || num_small);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('num_large BEFORE = 10, AFTERWARDS = ' || num_large );

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semi-colons in declaration section. Should be

```
DECLARE
   num_small  NUMBER := 20;
   num_large  NUMBER := 10;
   temp       NUMBER;
BEGIN
   IF num_small > num_large
   THEN
      temp := num_small;

      num_small := num_large;

      num_large := temp;
   END IF;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('num_small BEFORE = 20, AFTERWARDS = ' || num_small);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('num_large BEFORE = 10, AFTERWARDS = ' || num_large);
END;
/
```

Comment: And while TEMP may not be a reserved word in this context, it looks suspicious.  Why not avoid the possibility of accidentally trying to use a reserved word for a name, by coming up with some good naming standards.  Like perhaps all local variables begin with 'L_'.  All variable (and table column) names being in the format 'adjective_noun'.  So your 'TEMP' would become L_TEMP_VAR.  Your other variables would be 'l_small_num' and 'l_large_num'.